# Trying to make a double pendulum swing simulation, but it keeps doing weird movements

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation

So I'm still a beginner in blender and I'm trying to make a simulation of a double pendulum. My problem is that the swings keep glitching out of their positions and wouldn't swing properly.

I watched a tutorial about some dynamic rigid body strings (https://youtu.be/ydX7bzLFbTo) and thought it might be cool to make a pendulum with just two swinging objects.

There are three objects in the scene:

1. The holder - set to rigid body passive
2. First swing - rigid body active
3. Third swing - rigid body active

There are also two additional empties set to hinge constraint that act as pivot points between the objects.

Blend file: [image]

[image: The setup]

[image: Some weird behaviour]

This is what happens when I press the play button for the simulation.

I tried setting the objects so that they don't intersect, got the same result.

If I don't use hinges but points, the same thing happens but also in other axes.

I ran out of ideas so I hope someone could help me with this one.

Comment: For simulations always make sure you ‘Apply Scale’ on any meshes that have been resized - this really can make all the difference.

Comment: See also [Double Pendulum in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/309912/60486)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: I somehow managed to get it working. Not sure which setting it was because I changed a few and then tested. I believe the problem was that the size of the model was too small.
[image]

Comment: wow, congrats! i didn't make it. And i never had thought that this would work, without parenting the second hinge....